# Correlation between a nominal and a continous rasters in R

Tags: raster, r, correlation

I have two rasters of which one has nominal scale and the other has continuous scale. I used rasterCorrelation() function from spatialEco package in R and got a sensible map as well. But as one raster is at nominal scale, I am not sure about how do we explain it? rasterCorrelation() uses a matrix cum window of some specified scale. Statistically it's not possible to calculate correlation of nominal vs any variable because of zero variance. Then what is rasterCorrelation() function doing?

Comment: If by "nominal scale" you mean it is a categorical value (eg one of sand/clay/silt/rock for soil data) then it might be using the underlying numeric codes for each one, probably the integers from 1 to N where N is the number of classes.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, it's a raster file LULC (Land Use Land Cover ) and yes categories are coded by numerical values. But the ordering does not have any meaning. The resulting correlation map is quite sensible. But I am not sure whether it's a valid/correct method.